# GridEngine Or Akka

Tags: akka, sungridengine, akka-cluster, akka-remote-actor

I am building an application that relies on some processing performed by a third party product (TPP). The distributors of this TPP recommend deploying it on GridEngine (for parallelisation etc...)

The interface to this TPP will be a REST API built on Scala & Akka.

Assuming the processing is something akin to handing off processing to a database or similar TPP, would I be be able to achieve this parallelisation using Akka and its Load Balancing, Routing, Cluster and Remote Actor features instead of GridEngine altogether?

My understanding of GridEngine is that it provides cluster management tools. It manages load among slaves and you hand it a job to complete and it allocates to an available slave. Is this possibly all achievable using just Akka? Would there be any specific reason to go with GridEngine?

Thanks

Comment: Just some extra info... The third party product is built on C++ and is called as an executable.

Comment: It doesn't look like Grid Engine has been updated in a couple of years.

Comment: Hi sourcedelica, Would you take that to mean that its on the path to deprecation? What I am really asking here is does GridEngine provide anything that I couldn't achieve with Akka?

Comment: Akka is a toolkit and has the tools to build all sorts of distributed designs. It is probably lower level than Grid Engine, meaning you will need to write custom code, but on the other hand Akka will be more flexible.  So